# Loading uiviews efficiently on iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, uiview

I have 20 uiviews class that are labelled "Question1","Question2","Question3" and etc all the way to "Question20".

In my main controller, I tried to have a method called nextQuestion and pass an argument of the current question number to it. However, I wish to find a way to alloc init the correct Question view.

I ended up doing something like this which is not correct.

UIView *nextLevel = [[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Question%i",levelNow] alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320)];

Could someone help me with this?
Thanks

Comment: Yes, go for a UILabel and set content with the text property. Just instantiate once and set text for the current question.

Answer (score 1):

You create a string and then you call *alloc* on it. However, *alloc* can only be used on classes. So you're missing the step going from a string to a class. This gap can be closed with *NSClassFromString*:

```
Class viewClass = NSClassFromString([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Question%i",levelNow]);
UIView *nextLevel = [[viewClass alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320)];
```